# Changing the font of text send as an email using mule

Tags: mule, mule-component

I want the font of text that is sent to mail using mule smtp connector to be changed.I am not using html.

Answer (score 1):

Use HTML.

Also preflight your email with http://premailer.dialect.ca/ to make sure it will render fine in most mail agents.

Comment: But David is it possible in case of text?

Comment: No, the rendering of plain text emails is controlled by the mail agent used to reading it.